# Event viewreset is not fired in leaflet version 1.0.2

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, leaflet

I am using d3 with Leaflet (v 1.0.2) and need to catch the `viewreset` event, but it's not fired.

```
this.map.on("viewreset", () => console.log("VIEW RESET"));
```

Is anyone else having this problem? I'm able to catch the `zoomend` event for example.

Also, manipulating positions and etc. on svg-layers is a bit of a pain as well in the new versions of Leaflet...but that is another story.

JSFidlle showing the problem http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html

Comment: Can you provide a little more code please? For example where are you calling this `on("viewreset")` event bind?

Comment: Hi! Here is a jsfiddle with the problem http://jsfiddle.net/LnzN2/558/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4837

> in 1.0, layers will have to rely on both zoom (zoom change) and viewreset (full reset of a layer). This was necessary to implement flyTo and other arbitrary animations.

And in: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3278

> remove viewreset event and depend solely on zoom event in layers instead

So viewreset event is no longer triggered on zoom.

Comment: Hi! Seems like it's removed as you say. If I look at the D3SvgOverlay [link](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay) project they use if-statements to catch other events than view reset as well for leaflet above version 1.

Thanks for the answer.